# how animation-direction works in css3 animation?

Tags: css, animation

As i understand, when i change the animation-direction from normal to reverse during a specific animation, the element will move towards the opposite direction right away starting from where it is now.But it seems i am wrong , here is the http://codepen.io/johnwaynerui/pen/bZvRLm When i click the reverse button, the circle does not turn around right away and moving towards the opposite direction. Are there something i misunderstand?

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <button id='reverse'>reverse</button>
@keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
   60% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
   80% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
   100% {
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
}

    #circle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius:25px;
        background-color: teal;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-name: move-right;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        position:absolute;
        left:30%;
        top:20%; 
    }

    #circle.reverse {
      animation-direction: reverse;
    }
    $('#reverse').click(function () {
      $('#circle').toggleClass('reverse');
    });
```

Comment: Your codepen link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> You can check the documentation for `animation-direction` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction).

It clearly states that, for a `reverse` value:
*The animation plays backward each cycle. Each time the animation cycles, the animation resets to the end state and starts over again.*

As per my understanding, the moment you add `animation-direction: reverse;` to your animation, it goes in reverse direction mode that means the end-point of original animation becomes its start-point and vice-versa. So, if your animation has run first 20% and you change its `animation-direction` to `reverse` its start and end-points get interchanged, and it suddenly jumps to the 20% point relative to these changed end-points. That's why you notice that your circle suddenly jumps to far right and then continues its movement towards left.

```js
$('#reverse').click(function () {
  $('#circle').toggleClass('reverse');
});
```

```css
@keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
   60% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
   80% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
   100% {
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
}

    #circle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius:25px;
        background-color: teal;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-name: move-right;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        position:absolute;
        left:30%;
        top:20%; 
    }
 #circle.reverse {
      animation-direction: reverse;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <button id='reverse'>reverse</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I know why it behaves like that!